# Format request after user entry Integromat?

Tags: make.com

Have a custom app... The output I need to be like the first sample . Does this need to be handled in the communication area to alter it or is there a certain parameter type and JSON to get it to output this way after user entry?

```
**Needs to be like this**

"customField": 
    {
      "kp14ZxNc79KW8ve9aprQ": "red"
    }
 

**Instead of this.**

 "customField": {
            "id": "kp14ZxNc79KW8ve9aprQ",
            "value": "red"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterate functionality in the communication tab and use output to display data

```
 "response": {
    "iterate": "{{body}}",
    "output": {
        "label": "{{customField.id}}",
        "value": "{{customField.value}}",
        "error": {
            "message": "ErrorCode: [{{statusCode}}] {{body.message}} description: {{body.description}}"
        }
    }
```